# How to add multiple trendlines pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, trendline

I have plotted a graph with two y axes and would now like to add two separate trendlines for each of the y plots.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

amp_costs=pd.read_csv('/Users/Ampicillin_Costs.csv', index_col=None, usecols=[0,1,2])
amp_costs.columns=['PERIOD', 'ITEMS', 'COST PER ITEM']

ax=amp_costs.plot(x='PERIOD', y='COST PER ITEM', color='Blue', style='.', markersize=10)
amp_costs.plot(x='PERIOD', y='ITEMS', secondary_y=True,
color='Red', style='.', markersize=10, ax=ax)
```

Any guidance as to how to plot these two trend lines to this graph would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you did just that in your code. What is the problem? What kind of output did you get? Please make a minimal reproducible example for us. It makes it so much easier to answer questions that way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: What kind of trendline? Linear?  Rolling Average?  What isn't working in your code?  what have you tried?

Comment: @DemetriP Linear...This code is working fine however I am unsure where to start in order to add 2 trendlines - 1 for each set of plotted data.

Comment: You'll need to add another column in your dataframe to represent the trend line.  Look at statsmodels.ols or sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how to use `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` to make the trend line.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
plt.style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline

period = np.arange(10)
items = -2*period +1 + np.random.randint(-2,2,len(period))
cost = 35000*period +15000 + np.random.randint(-25000,25000,len(period))
data = np.vstack((period,items,cost)).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=\['P','ITEMS', 'COST'\]).set_index('P')


lmcost = LinearRegression().fit(period.reshape(-1,1), cost.reshape(-1,1))
lmitems = LinearRegression().fit(period.reshape(-1,1), items.reshape(-1,1))

df['ITEMS_LM'] = lmitems.predict(period.reshape(-1,1))
df['COST_LM'] = lmcost.predict(period.reshape(-1,1))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()


df.ITEMS.plot(ax = ax, color = 'b')
df.ITEMS_LM.plot(ax = ax,color= 'b', linestyle= 'dashed')
df.COST.plot(ax = ax, secondary_y=True, color ='g')
df.COST_LM.plot(ax = ax, secondary_y=True, color = 'g', linestyle='dashed')
```

[image]

Comment: 'amp_costs=pd.read_csv('/Users/Ampicillin_Costs.csv', index_col=None, usecols=[1,2])
amp_costs.columns=['ITEMS', 'COST PER ITEM']
z = np.polyfit(x=amp_costs.loc[:, amp_costs['COST PER ITEM']], y=amp_costs.loc[:, amp_costs['ITEMS']], deg=1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
amp_costs['trendline'] = p(amp_costs.loc[:, amp_costs['COST PER ITEM']])

x=amp_costs['COST PER ITEM']
y=amp_costs['ITEMS']
ax = amp_costs.plot.scatter(x, y)
amp_costs.set_index(x, inplace=True)
amp_costs.trendline.sort_index(ascending=False).plot(ax=ax)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.show()'